# how to read from smart card reader in verifone vx520?

Tags: point-of-sale, verifone

I want to read data from smart card and use APDU to read and write to the smart card. I don't have LIBVOY.A in my sdk. Where can I download the library?Here is my code but it doesn't read any data from smart card.

```
handle = open("/dev/icc1",0);
wait_evt(EVT_ICC1_INS);
read(handle, buf, 20);
printf("reading:%s",buf);
```

Comment: Check out the "Verix V CardSlot" download on DevNet.  Not sure if that will have what you need or not, but it's worth a shot...

Comment: Do you have a `voyn.lib` file? The cardslot library is definitely the way to go (although a little tricky to setup)